# Show $\log z_1z_2 \neq \log z_1 + \log z_2$ given $z_1 = i$ and $z_2 = -\sqrt 3 + i$.

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms

Show by evaluating both sides that for $z_1 = i$ and $z_2 = -\sqrt 3 + i$,

$\log z_1z_2 \neq \log z_1 + \log z_2$.

Recall the definition: $$\log z = \log |z| + i\arg z$$

**Attempt:**

*Left side:*

$\log z_1z_2 = \log [i (-\sqrt 3 + i)] = \log[  i^2 - \sqrt 3i] = \log |- 1 - \sqrt 3 i| + i\arg(-1 - \sqrt 3i) = \log 2 + i(4\pi/3)$

*and right side:*

$\log z_1 + \log z_2 =  \log i + \log (-\sqrt 3 + i) = {\log|i| + i\arg(i)} + {\log|-\sqrt 3 + i)|} + i\arg(-\sqrt 3 + i) = \log 1 + i (\pi/2) + \log 2 + i(5\pi/6) = \log 2 + i(\pi/2 + 5\pi/6) =  \log 2 + i(4\pi/3) $.

But I get the same answer. Can someone please tell where the error is? Any feedback will really help. Thank you.

Comment: Note that whether equality holds depends on which branch of $\log$ is used: Since $\arg i = \frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\arg (-\sqrt{3} + i) = \frac{4 \pi}{3}$, equality holds, e.g., for the (frequently used) branch whose argument takes values in $[0, 2 \pi)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $Arg(z)$  function spits out the principle argument, which is in the range $(-\pi,\pi]$.  So your answer to the first one is wrong, it should be $\frac {-2\pi}3 i$ as the imaginary part

Comment: is the second part fine?

Comment: Yes, and this is the behavior that shows why the rule fails...adding two principle arguments often leads to a non principle one

Comment: how did you find $-2\pi/3$? as the correct angle?

Comment: I subtracted $2\pi$ from your answer,  to get it into the right interval.  Remember that $2\pi$ is the period of the unit circle, if you are outside of that, add or subtract in incriments of $2\pi$ until you get to within $(-\pi,\pi]$

Answer (score 0):

The principal-branch Arg is always between $-\pi$ and $\pi$, so $\text{Arg}(-1-i\sqrt{3})$ is not $4\pi/3$.