# Principal Value of Logarithm Log(z1/z2)=Log(z1)-Log(z2) holds?

Tags: logarithms

the question is whether
$$
\log\left(\frac{z_1}{z_2}\right)=\log(z_1) - \log(z_2)
$$
holds for any non-zero complex numbers $z_1$ and $z_2$.

Here, $\log$ is the principal value of the logarithm, with definition
$$
\log(z) = \ln|z| + i \text{Arg}z
$$

I have tried to substitute $z_1$ and $z_2$ by their polar forms, $r_1 e^{i \theta_1}$ and $r_2 e^{i \theta_2}$ respectively, but then I get to

$$
\ln(r_1) -\ln(r_2) + i^{\theta_1 - \theta_2}
$$

which is not what i want. Any help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show $\log z_1z_2 \neq \log z_1 + \log z_2$ given $z_1 = i$ and $z_2 = -\sqrt 3 + i$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1227919/show-log-z-1z-2-neq-log-z-1-log-z-2-given-z-1-i-and-z-2-sqrt-3)